# Calculating the GCD in python

Tags: python

so i have this for school project. 
I want to calculate the GCD of two numbers, to do that you need to find the divisors of the 2 number, then find the biggest divisor in the results. 
The first step i was able to do it :

```
n1=int(input("Write the first number"))
n2=int(input("Write the second number"))

for i in range(1,n1+1):
    if n1%i==0:
        s=i
        print(s)

for i in range(1,n2+1):
    if n2%i==0:
        z=i
        print(z)
```

but I wasnt able to compare all  the results of s and z, Any solution? 
ps: I know there is a ready function for this in python but i need to code my own

Comment: I thought in this but wasnt able to code it, tried a lot.. what to do?

Comment: Can you please give me a code, i had all those ideas but wasnt able to code it

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You can store the values of s and z as a set and find the intersection of both.

Here is the sample code:

```
n1=int(input("Write the first number"))
n2=int(input("Write the second number"))

n1list = []
n2list = []

for i in range(1,n1+1):
    if n1%i==0:
       n1list.append(i)

for i in range(1,n2+1):
    if n2%i==0:
        n2list.append(i)

n3 = list(set(n1list) & set(n2list))
print(n3[-1]) #This will return the highest value in the list, i.e GCD
```

Comment: Note that sets are unordered, so their intersection is unordered as well, and the last element of `n3` may not be the maximum value (perhaps Python keeps them ordered under the hood, but as far as I'm aware, that is not guaranteed). Use `max(set(n1list) & set(n2list))` instead. In fact, you can do away with the lists, change n1list and n2list to sets, and `.add()` elements to the sets instead of appending to a list.

Answer (score -1):

```
def gcd(x, y):
while y != 0:
    (x, y) = (y, x % y)
return x
```

This function finds the GCD for two numbers.

```
n1=int(input("Write the first number"))
n2=int(input("Write the second number"))

print(gcd(n1,n2))
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, can you explain this part for me please:    (x, y) = (y, x % y)

Comment: Check this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_algorithm . It is a one-liner because of pythons swap capabilities.